# Playing audio in cocos2d v3

Tags: ios, audio, cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

I am trying to get background music playing and looping as well as one-shot sounds every now and again, e.g. level up etc.

I have found many tutorials on this that are using SimpleAudioEngine, but when I import SimpleAudioEngine.h the compiler is stating "SimpleAudioEngine.h file not found"

I am using SpriteBuilder and cocos2d v3.

Does anyone know where I can get this class from?

Thanks

Comment: v3 uses ObjectAL as audio engine. I thin the class is named OALSimpleAudio http://kstenerud.github.io/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/documentation/index.html

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been pulling my hair out :-) I'll take a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playBg:@"bakground.caf" loop:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for that. looks quite easy but I'm getting: Could not find full path of file BGSounds.aifc.  I have it in the SpriteBuilder Resources/resources-auto directory.  I'll have a play see if I can get it working by specifying a full dir.  Thanks

Comment: found it!  Needed to add the sound file to the Xcode resources rather than just drop it in the directory.  Works perfect, thanks.

Comment: great..too bad i saw your comment a little late.. but it feels wonderful when you find a solution yourself.. best of luck!

Comment: Do sound effects need to be the .caf format? Can they be .wav files?

Comment: @allthewayapps I tried working with .wav , but it didn't work. I guess OALSimpleAudio doesn't support .wav format

Comment: @abhineetprasad Ok, thank you. Could you recommend any tools to convert to .caf? I can't seem to find any.

Comment: I use audacity. You can export the file as .caf by choosing "other uncompressed files" option.

Comment: I found that apple has a command line tool for converting audio called afconvert, this is a nice tutorial on converting audio which covers afconvert: http://www.raywenderlich.com/233/audio-tutorial-for-ios-converting-and-recording